# In Microsoft Dynamics 365, why is my filter not a combo box when I am running start my Visual Studio Project?

Tags: forms, combobox, constraints, filtering, dynamics-365-operations

I'm currently following the tutorial "[Creating a custom filter control](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/dynamics-365-for/9781786468864/3d2be95c-79a9-49a0-9bc1-172687a3900a.xhtml)" in [Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations Development Cookbook - Fourth Edition](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/dynamics-365-for/)

I've created the extension to the `MainAccount` which includes, under NavigationList(Group) -> Filter (Group)", an instance of `Combo Box` with the following properties:

```
| Property        | Value                      |
| Name            | FilterType                 |
| AutoDeclaration | Yes                        |
| EnumType        | DimensionLedgerAccountType |
| Selection       | 10                         |
```

In Visual Studio's preview, this *displays* correctly and offers the expected set of values.

I've set my project to be my startup project.
I've set my form extension to be my startup object.
... and then I click "Start".

After some long wait for the page to render, I find the labels for the fields are displayed with short black lines where the input fields should be, but the input fields hardly allow any interaction.  I can click on them to select them, transforming them into blue box shapes, but I can't actually type anything into them and the input which should be a drop-down/combo-box for "type" has no visual or functional distinctions from the input for "name" which should just be text.

Is Visual Studio failing to deploy something?
Is there some additional modification needed in my metadata for this to render as expected?
What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to FH-Inway who spent some time screen sharing, it turns out the problem was not with the solution but with my expectations.

I *expected* the filter fields to simply be displayed and immediately available for use.

However, in actually -- completely counter-intuitively -- the fields, being created as part of the form, are only editable after one clicks the "Edit" button.

Once in edit mode, the fields display and interact as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Because you mention that you click "Apply", I think you are in the wrong area of the form.

Take a look at the screenshot from [my implementation](https://github.com/FH-Inway/D365FOCookbook) of the recipe, you can see there are two filter areas on the form. The first is the standard filter experience and the listed fields are based on the ranges set on the query of the form. Those fields are text fields because they allow you to enter filter values which may be different from one possible value. The second area is the one where the two custom filter controls described by the recipe in the cookbook were added. As you can see in the screenshot, the "Main account type" control provides a combo box behavior with the allowed values. If you change a value in on of these two controls, you don't need to click "Apply". Instead, the filters are applied automatically when the `onModified` event of the control fires.

[image]

Comment: cheers for the response.  Do I need to do something to see my custom filters?  I could not find them.

Comment: Not sure why you are not seeing them. Maybe compare your implementation to [mine](https://github.com/FH-Inway/D365FOCookbook) and check if you can find any differences that might explain the different behavior.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but when I create the extension of the MainAccount form, I need to select a model, but the only model I am allowed to select is ExpenseManagement.

Comment: some further experiments confirmed that I am interacting with the wrong components, but (as I have declared in the revised question above), I'm still not getting the expected functionality.  While these fields are present, they do not accept input.

Comment: The behavior in your previous comment is most likely caused by a missing reference in your model. Check which model form `MainAccount` is part of, then check if that model is referenced in your model (see [Updating model references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-tools/models#updating-model-parameters)). You can also compare your Descriptor.xml file with [mine](https://github.com/FH-Inway/D365FOCookbook/blob/main/Metadata/D365FOCookbook/Descriptor/D365FOCookbook.xml) and check for differences.

Comment: Yours has three references mine did not have (Contact, Dimensions, and Directory), but adding these had no effect.  The only other difference is the value for Id, but I expect this should be unque....

Comment: I've tried in both Internet Explorer and Edge and the page displays the same result.  Under the hood, if I go to the JavaScript console, I see IE only gets one error ("The data-dyn-container needs to be set when both the template and the target have chldren.").   Edge has three more errors because resources failed to load and two more because it could not GET a couple things...  There are also some warnings, but I don't think they could be relevant.

Comment: Form `MainAccount` is part of the Ledger model. If your model references this model, you should be able to create an extension in your model. If that does not work or does not resolve your issue, there is probably not much that can be done without taking a look at your vm. As mentioned in another question/comment, it probably easier to restore the VM to a clean state and try again. If you add the information on what version of D365FO you are, I can check if my solution works on that version.

Comment: I tried cleaning and trying again, but still without success.  I think I'm on version 10.0.17...  At least that's the version I downloaded.  Microsoft updated a few things after I got the VM up and running... not sure where I might look for information if it updated D365.

Comment: When you are inside the D365FO application in the browser, you can click on the question mark in the top right corner, then about. This should tell you the version. I will try tomorrow to install my implementation on a 10.0.17 vm.

Comment: Cheers!  Installed product version : 10.0.17 (10.0.761.10019)
Installed platform version : Update41 (7.0.5934.35741)

Comment: I managed to install your solution into my instance of D365, but confirmed that your solution has the same rendering and interactivity problems as mine (at least, in my instance, obviously).  :-/

Comment: Strange, I also installed it on a clean 10.0.17 vm and it works just fine.